# How to use a custom class with silex ServiceProvider

Tags: php, class, symfony, templating, silex

I feel like I have searched the entire internet through and through, but cannot seem to figure this one out. I'm using Silex (the latest version) and cannot seem to figure out how to use Silex's ServiceProvider system to return an instance of a class for use.

I do know how to create a basic service provider.

What I do not know how to do is how to have this service provider use a custom class. I've tried everything I can think of or find on the web. Part of the problem is that Silex's documentation on this is not very extensive, and most of the questions that have been ask about this type of issue were asked/answered before a pretty large change to how it was done (or so it seems) so the answers are not current.

So, put briefly:
I want to use Silex's $app['myclass'] type system to access my class, so that I can do things like $app['myclass']->myMethod().

Where I'm hung up is this, while I can create a service provider, I can't figure out how to get the service provider to recognize the class. I've tried the whole namespace thing with the composer auto-load pso-0 set up, and have tried use MyClass/MyClass type things.

Haha, basically, because there is so little documentation, there could be any part of it that I am doing wrong.

**Would someone write a current step-by-step process for hooking up a custom library/class to the $app variable? I think this would help not only me, but also others.** Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me like you are having issues with class loading. This is something that used to be handled by the `autoload` service in silex. That service was removed however, in favour of composer's autoloading.

You were on the right track with specifying the autoloading in `composer.json`. In case you're not familiar with composer, read the [introduction](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). For details on how the autoloading works, see [the autoloading section of the basic usage chapter](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

I will give you the short version here. Make sure your filenames comply with the PSR-0 naming standard. Add this to your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Acme": "src/"}
    }
}
```

You need to replace `Acme` with your namespace and `src` with the base directory for your classes. For example, the class `Acme\Foo\Bar` would be located in `src/Acme/Foo/Bar.php`.

Then run `php composer.phar update` to get the autoload files re-dumped and you should be able to access your classes.

Comment: Hi igor, thanks for the prompt response--sorry it's taken me so long to get back. I've been working on finishing a different project and only now am back to working on this problem. Quick question, when you say 'Add this to your composer.json file' are you referring to the composer.json file in the root directory?

Comment: * That is, the root directory that contains the 'web' folder and 'vendor' folder.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've been reading up on Composer docs all afternoon, but still can't get the autoloader to work with classes. I've stepped out of Silex for the moment, just trying to get the autoload to work at the most basic level--but can't seem to. Here's a .zip of just the most basic files. I'm trying to load the custom class Fledge\Select. Can you take a look at it and tell me if there is anything wrong with it? [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95371450/customClass.zip)

Comment: You need to put `namespace Fledge;` at the top of the file.